# restartLoader in the onStart method throw Exception

Tags: android, android-compatibility

I am using the android compatibility   package to use Loaders . when i init a loader or restart it in the `onCreate` method , it just wroks find but when i restart or init it in the `onStart` it throw an error , what I  want know why " some times " when I  initLoader in the `onCreate` of the activity and click some button that  move me  quickly to another activity  before the loader bind the data to the UI ,and  return back to the activity that previously init the Loader the loader doesnot load the data "nothing appears on the UI ?!!!! so i thought that move the initLoader to `onStart` but it throw an error

```
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {biz.dot.khtmeh/biz.dot.khtmeh.ui.HomeScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is already a listener registered
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1173)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is already a listener registered
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.support.v4.content.Loader.registerListener(Loader.java:130)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.start(LoaderManager.java:259)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.installLoader(LoaderManager.java:509)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:496)
07-13 03:19:15.140: E/AndroidRuntime(23179):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.restartLoader(LoaderManager.java:642)
```

Comment: Your logcat clearly states your issue: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is already a listener registered" You're trying to register some kind of listener that has already been registered (IE. "at android.support.v4.content.Loader.registerListener(Loader.java:130)"). You should try checking to see if the listener is already registered before you do so.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely you are re-using a loader more than once.  Each time `onCreateLoader(..)` is called, you should be returning a new instance of a `Loader<T>`.

Comment: Good point. I had a problems with loader restarting, when I was returning static class instance from onCreateLoader()